# How to remove Lubuntu and GRUB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, lubuntu

So I broke my entire Ubuntu install (uninstalled Python3), and now I need to re-install Lubuntu. My only issue is that I'm pretty sure that if I reformat the partitions, GRUB will freak out, and won't let me boot to my new Lubuntu install. I have Lubuntu dual-boot with Windows.

What would be the process to delete Lubuntu and then reinstall it without harming any other partitions, and with GRUB working fully?

Comment: You can also not reformat partitions, and do a "dirty" install. Your data will remain (but you still should have good backups, just in case), and any system configuration files you edited will be overwritten with defaults. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation & 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1941872  But you also may want to change or add partitions now that you know a bi tmore about Lubuntu.

Comment: @explodingfilms101 if the answer provided solved your question could you mark it as the answer with the checkmark please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grub will not freak out if you reformat the partitions.

In fact, if you are on a single boot computer (just one Lubuntu installed),
Grub itself will also be formatted and reinstalled.

*Ergo*: There is no such risk.

The process is to make your Lubuntu install USB, boot from it, and tell it to "Erase and Install Lubuntu".

Be sure to fist copy all important files to the cloud or a USB drive.

Comment: So if I format first (I want to add more space to my Lubuntu partition) and then re-install, would that work?

Comment: @explodingfilms101 It depends. As long as you know what you're doing when managing partitions (and OS installation) it should work, either for single or dual-boot. And you can also follow the advice in the oldfred's comment below your question. The whole process seems to be trivial (for me) but I can't say how safe it will be for others.

Comment: @explodingfilms101 well I don't know what you meant by "would that work". yes you would have a perfectly bootable and functional OS with more space. your old files and programs will be deleted though. that's why I said to back up your files first.